# How to make django admin site to not recognize a foreign key'ed model (on different app) to be a model of current app?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin, foreign-keys

I have three models - two of them are in one app, and the third one is on the another. The structure is like this:

**taapp.models:**

```
class Teachers(model.Model):
    fullname = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    ...

class TeachersScale(model.Model):
    teacher = models.ForeignKey("Teachers")
    abbr = models.ForeignKey("questions.QuestionTypes")
```

**questions.models:**

```
class QuestionTypes(models.Model):
    abbr = models.CharField(max_length=5)
    ......
```

I registered all these models to admin:

**taapp.admin:**

```
from taapp.models import Teachers
from taapp.models import TeachersScale
from django.contrib import admin

from admin_forms import TeachersAdmin, TeachersScaleAdmin

admin.site.register(Teachers, TeachersAdmin)
admin.site.register(TeachersScale, TeachersScaleAdmin)
```

**taapp.admin_forms:**

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib import admin

class TeachersAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('fullname', 'email', 'registration_date')

class TeachersScaleAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('teacher', 'abbr')
    list_filter = ['teacher','abbr']
```

When I try to add a field to `TeachersScale` in admin site, I get the following error:

```
DatabaseError at /admin/taapp/teachersscale/add/ 
(1146, "Table 'taapp.questions_questiontypes' doesn't exist")
```

It treats `QuestionTypes`, as it is a model in `taapp`. How to solve it? Or is there something wrong with my db design?

I tried `TabularInline` for `QuestionTypes` to see if reverse adding works. Well, it works:

**questions.admin:**

```
class TeachersScaleInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = TeachersScale

class QuestionTypesAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [TeachersScaleInline]
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Following the discussion in the answer of Peter DeGlopper, it would be interesting to read about your database design (and maybe a rationale for it). You should not confuse MySQL features and django database layout based on model definitions...

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you haven't actually created your questions table, or if you have you've forced it into a different database. Foreign keys expect to share the same database, and it's perfectly standard to have multiple apps sharing the same database. That's why the app name is part of the automatically generated table name.

Comment: Oh, I see now. My apps are on different dbs. Is there any way to force django to add a data to a table in another database - like it did, when `tabularinline` is used in `questiontypes` mode? Also, I couldn't understand: If Foreign keys expect to be in a same db, why mysql allows to create a relation between databases?

Comment: Django can handle multiple databases (the docs are pretty good), but it doesn't have any official support for foreign keys from one database to another. To speculate about why not - Django's multiple databases aren't limited to different databases on the same server. I have one project that uses mysql for all its writable data, but also reads from a MS SQL database.